# nested for loops in a for loop, print each to new file

Tags: python, mongodb, for-loop, while-loop, pymongo

I'm trying to do something I'm sure is simple. But I'm a bit baffled.

I have 3 `for` loops, each time the `for` loops runs it takes a certain piece of data from the next document in the database. So if I change `LastWrite_Time['result'][:1]` to `LastWrite_Time['result'][:2]` then I get the date string from the first 2 documents in the directory.

I want to print the `LastWrite_Time`, `DeltaTimeBetweenPoints`, `Data` together for the first document, then again for the second document, until the nth document. I have been trying some while loop stuff but I'm just not getting there. And if possible print each not a new file, but I think I figure out the last bit.

```
for T in LastWrite_Time['result'][:n]:
        print 'Time & Date =',T['value']

for D in DeltaTimeBetweenPoints['result'][:n]:
    print D['value']

for a in Data['result'][:n]:      #only print the first result in the list
    print a['value']
```

Comment: Yes ,`[:1]` will give you a list consisting of the first item only. If you don't want that, don't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list1 = LastWrite_Time['result']
list2 = DeltaTimeBetweenPoints['result']
list3 = Data['result']

for T, D, A in zip(list1, list2, list3):
    print 'Time & Date =',T['value']
    print D['value']
    print a['value']
```

This will at first take the 1st element of each list and print values, then the 2nd element of each list and print them, and so on.

[zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) takes lists and iterates the elements from each list one by one, for all the lists.